# SupportMapFragment loading on the main thread and freezing the interface (getMapAsync ignored)

Tags: java, android, google-maps

In a default `SupportMapFragment` the MapView is being loaded and created when the Fragment is instantied thus doing the heavy work on the Main Thread.

The log below happens before `getMapAsync(this);` is called and it is the moment when the Main Thread freezes for about 2 seconds. **The log proves somehow that everything is being created before `getMapAsync()`**.

Isn't the map supposed to load ONLY when `getMapAsync()` is called?

```
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xb7966f90 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb7988688
I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
I/zzy: Making Creator dynamically
W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.704ms
D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Loading module com.google.android.gms.maps from APK /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/chimera-module-root/module-fcfb08c37b9ca44c48d9936b0e1895ef8b9cffe0/MapsModule.apk
D/ChimeraModuleLdr: Loading module APK /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/chimera-module-root/module-fcfb08c37b9ca44c48d9936b0e1895ef8b9cffe0/MapsModule.apk
D/ChimeraFileApk: Primary ABI of requesting process is armeabi-v7a
D/ChimeraFileApk: Classloading successful. Optimized code found.
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 7895000
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 8115236
I/e: Token loaded from file. Expires in: 393978062 ms.
I/e: Scheduling next attempt in 393678 seconds.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

This is the fragment:

```
public class StoreMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment
        implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    public static StoreMapFragment newInstance() {
        StoreMapFragment fragment = new StoreMapFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;
        loadStores();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    public void loadStores() {
        if(mMap == null)
            return;

        // Add markers
    }
}
```

**Related:**

- [First launch of Activity with Google Maps is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178212/first-launch-of-activity-with-google-maps-is-very-slow/27599226#27599226)
- [what makes my map fragment loading slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265526/what-makes-my-map-fragment-loading-slow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved by delaying the fragment instantiation.

First, I added the SupportMapFragment inside another Fragment, and then I delayed the `SupportMapFragment` instantiation as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26463681/332839).

**StoreMapFragment.java**

```
public class StoreMapFragment extends Fragment
        implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        if (mMap == null) {
            final OnMapReadyCallback listener = this;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (isAdded()) {
                        mMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
                        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
                        fm.beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.map, mMapFragment).commit();
                        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(listener);
                    }
                }
            }, 1000);
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;
        loadStores();
    }
}
```

**fragment_map.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: it's seem use framelayout instead of using fragment make less delay when open page in navigationdrawer.

Answer (score 1):

You should get your map in `onViewCreated()` method:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mMap = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().
            findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mMap.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

This would not cause any delay in loading your map.