# Google Maps slow loading

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to load a simple google maps using support fragment. everything works properly but the initial load causes jank and skips frames. There is nothing in the activity apart from the google map fragment. Is there anything I am doing wrong here? Would appreciate your inputs

Log

```
02-19 17:00:23.868 22747-22747/com.demo.android I/MainActivity: onCreate: Start
02-19 17:00:23.908 22747-22747/com.demo.android I/zzbz: Making Creator dynamically
02-19 17:00:23.913 22747-22747/com.demo.android I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:18
02-19 17:00:23.913 22747-22747/com.demo.android I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 18
02-19 17:00:23.943 22747-22747/com.demo.android W/zygote64: Unsupported class loader
02-19 17:00:24.022 22747-22747/com.demo.android I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 11910000
02-19 17:00:24.031 22747-22747/com.demo.android I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 11975940
02-19 17:00:24.490 22747-22761/com.demo.android I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=110KB, data=101KB
02-19 17:00:24.490 22747-22761/com.demo.android I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=100KB, data=63KB
02-19 17:00:24.662 22747-22747/com.demo.android I/MainActivity: onCreate: End
02-19 17:00:24.680 22747-22747/com.demo.android I/Choreographer: Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-19 17:00:24.741 22747-22747/com.demo.android I/MainActivity: onMapReady:
```

Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("MainActivity", "onCreate: Start");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.mapfrag);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    Log.i("MainActivity", "onCreate: End");
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.i("MainActivity", "onMapReady: ");
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
            .title("Marker in Sydney"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
```

Layout

```
<fragment
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mapfrag"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.demo.android.MainActivity"/>
```

Dependency

```
//Google Maps dependency
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
```

Comment: Any Ideas?  Do let me know

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178212/first-launch-of-activity-with-google-maps-is-very-slow?rq=1][1]